# Reusing html like templates without a view engine

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tiles

This is for a new application, there's going to be several servers handling different parts (one for htmls, one as a proxy to handle https requests, and a full java backend with a database). The view server is supposed to be as simple as possible (an apache server delivering the htmls and that's it)

The idea is to use the pure htmls (with JS) that the UI designed created. Now, I thought of making the entire application using Jquery, by pulling all the dynamic data and append js files with logic on how to handle the ajax response.

My problem comes when I want to reuse htmls (the header, the footer and the menu are exactly the same for all pages). I can call, for example, /contact.html, and through ajax, call header.html, footer.html and menu.html. But that would mean 4 GET requests only for the main page (plus, rendering could be really off until all requests are finished).

I also don't want to have single full pages, because if I want to change the menu, I have to make that change in every html.

Is there some other alternative I'm missing ? If not, what is the best approach here (performance AND maintenance are equally important here)

Comment: if you're creating a single page app, then it's no problem. I'm assuming you aren't. In most cases, header, footer, etc. will be handled with a server-side language. Other than that I suppose you can create your header/footer via a js function, and just call that on each page.

Comment: Browsers are faster (a lot) at rendering HTML, than they are at building it via Javascript. You can obviously repeat your HTML elements on the server by "dumb" copy & paste -- but that's tedious & decreases maintainability. Thus the reason to use a "smart" server-side language.

Comment: Actually, a single page application could be a possible solution I hadn't considered. Only 2 concerns: a) I need different urls for each page b) Each page needs to get indexed by google. Are these possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Try http://mixer2.org/ .
Mixer2 can load html templates and convert them to java bean instance.
All the html tag and org.mixer2.xhtml.* java class are mapped one by one automatically.
So, You can load several templates such as "header.html", "footer.html", and re-use the tag snippet copy.